# Is there a command in Visual Studio Code That will convert your java project into an executable jar file?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar

I am going to participate in a game jam tomorrow, and I am going to make the game with java in visual studio code. The only problem is once I finish the game I don't know how to export it to an executable jar file. I am posting this question to ask if there is a command in visual studio code that will allow me to export it.

Comment: have you read the VSC docs for Java

Comment: Are you using Maven ?

Comment: Think in terms of "deploying a Java application." There is no such concept as "convert to executable."  If you search for how to deploy an application from VSC, you should find some quick answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your project is no build tools, so here is my solution about export ing projects to jars. Turn to folder `src`:

1. Compile the .java file with `main` method, which generates the .class file:

   ```
    javac App.java
   ```
2. Generate .jar:

   ```
    jar cvfe App.jar App .\
   ```
3. Run the jar:

   ```
    java -jar App.jar
   ```

[image]

Detailed command information, please view [The Jar Command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jar.html).